# Domain of Holomorphy

Tags: several-complex-variables

How to show that $D=\{ |z_1|<1\} \cup \{ |z_2|<1\} \subset \mathbb{C}^2$ is not a domain of holomorphy. What is the smallest domain of holomorphy $ S\supset D $ ?

I think we cannot just add the distinguished boundary (the torus $|z_1|=1, |z_2|=1$) to $D$ because it would violate analiticity. Should we use logarithmically convexity argument to extend our domain? Can anyone help?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

For Reinhardt domains, recognizing domains of holomorphy is a lot simpler than for general domains.

To see that the $D$ in question is *not* a domain of holomorphy, the easiest is probably to use the following theorem on convergence of power series:

**Theorem** Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ be a connected Reinhardt domain containing $0$ and assume that $f$ is holomorphic on $\Omega$. Then the power series of $f$ around the origin converges (normally) on $\tilde \Omega$ -- *the logarithmically convex hull of $\Omega$*.

Hence any function holomorphic on $\Omega$ extends to $\tilde\Omega$. In fact more is true, namely $\tilde\Omega$ is the smallest domain of holomorphy containing $\Omega$. So in your case, you want to find $\tilde D$.

It's also possible to see that $D$ is not a domain of holomorphy by a "pushing discs" argument, but this is a bit messy to write down explicitly.

For a reference to the above theorem, see for example Krantz, *Function theory of several complex variables*. In my (somewhat old) edition, it's proposition 2.3.16. The proof follows from Cauchy's integral formula on polydiscs, and is not very difficult.